# Magento 2.1.15 - PHPSESSID changes from page to page

Tags: customer-session, cm-redissession

I am having an issue with Magento seemingly losing sessions and thereby logging users out.

I have also noticed that the PHPSESSID cookie value seems to change within one user session. Is that the expected behavior?

I do have AJAX calls that check if a user is logged in or not, and I am wondering if somehow the cookie value that the AJAX calls get back from the controllers are causing the logout issue?

I am using Redis for session management on AWS